# The method build() is undefined for the type Notification.Builder

Tags: android

Error: The method build() is undefined for the type Notification.Builder

I have add android-support-v4.jar still I got error ?

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setWhen(when)
        .setContentIntent(intent).build();
```

Answer (score 6):

My guess is that your `android-support-v4.jar` is too old. `build()` was added about a year ago, but well after the Android Support package was first released.

Ensure that you have the latest Android Support package downloaded in your SDK Manager, then copy over the latest `android-support-v4.jar` from the `extras/` directory of your SDK into your project.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    context);
        Notification notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(when)
                    .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
                    .setContentText(message).build();

            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you are targeting your os after Honeycomb then you will need to implement NotificationCompat.Builder class.

Comment: Great! What a relief :)!